# Can I dynamically/logically alias columns in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

The base table looks like this and will only contain 1 or 2 rows (likely 1):

```
| Column A | Column B | Column C | 2021 | 2022 |
| -------- | -------- | -------- |:----:|:----:|
| TEXT     | TEXT     | TEXT     | 0.5  |  1.5 |
```

Columns A, B and C names will likely remain static but the columns with the YYYY will keep moving forward. The desired output is to alias 2021 as 202101, 202102, 202103....202112. The same would happen for 2022.

I'm wondering if there's a way to do this dynamically so that even when the column name changes, it works similar to a CONCAT function. As an example, next January, the columns will read 2022 and 2023. If this data was in the rows, I would write it as **CONCAT(YYYYdata),'M01'** and repeat 12 times which would work perfectly fine but don't know how to tackle this when each column name is what I need picked up and the columns keep changing.

Can this be done? My google-fu hasn't landed me any results that did the trick (yet)!

Comment: That's not proper database design.  If A/B/C are the key, then you have one table with A, B, C, and an ID,  Then you have a second table with ID, year, month, and data.  You don't use dynamic columns names.  That's simply not maintainable.

Comment: #1 Generally a bad idea. #2 Recommend read as rows and use your application code to format it. #3 However if you want to lean the hardway(tm), the google fu term is "pivot-table". Any problem see #1 and #2.

Comment: This isn't a relational schema, so there isn't a relational solution.

Comment: @TimRoberts I wholeheartedly agree. However, this table is actually a data extract/dump from an application for the sole purpose of transforming the data (which can't be done within the app) and the resulting view would be a source that the app imports in from. If I don't do this on the MySQL side, I'd have to create 12 unique import steps within the app to pull in the same value for 2021, 12 more steps for 2022 and so on.

Comment: @danblack I think this makes sense and is what I suspected but didn't know if there was some other means of calling upon a column based on position, etc. I'll give it a go with the time data by row, CONCAT and then pivot the results to achieve the desired outcome. Thank you, sir!

Comment: @tadman Agreed - long time lurker but first time poster and am realizing that I should have called out that this is for the sole purpose of transforming some data and there is no bigger picture (i.e. relational solution) that it ties into.

Comment: If you can restructure it, your life will be a lot easier. If not, only road is the hard road.